# Text appearing on top of section featuring large number of tables and graphs, instead of in middle

Tags: tables, spacing, floats, text

I have a section of a report that is mostly entirely figures and tables, but I need to add a small bit of text explaining a calculation located between a table and a following figure. I type the text in the desired location, but instead it places it at the beginning of the section, above everything.

This is the start of the section:

```
\section{Data, Observations, and Calculations}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[]{"CdSe Absorbances".png}
```

This is where I want to add the text:

```
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

In order to determine the size of the CdSe Quantum Dots, I performed the 
following calculations:


\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
```

There is an end{figure} for the first set of figures, so its not that messing with anything.

Comment: Welcome ! Please provide a so called minimal working example starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document`  and that shows the problem your are facing.

Comment: If you don't want images and tables to move around (float), don't use the floating `figure` and `table` environments. If you want your images and tables to have captions, you could use the `captionof` command from the `capt-of` package.

Comment: the _only_ reason to use `figure` is to allow the content to be moved. Also avoid using `[h]` or `[!h]` latex will usually warn you about that and chaneg it to `[ht]` but `[htp]` is better and gives latex more options to place the figure.